# NS Failure on AWS hosted domain name: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN. How can I resolve an unidentified DNS failure?

Tags: networking, dns, domain, amazon-web-services

My website does not load, but the app loads from elastic beanstalk just fine. I have NOT made any configuration changes, other than deploying a new version of the app, which works correctly.

- Domain Name:  [ `danhenning.us` / `www.danhenning.us` ]
- EB URL:  `dan-henning-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com`

Domain name is hosted with AWS, but the Registrar URL: [ `whois.gandi.net` ]

- Website does NOT load when using the domain name, but the corresponding Elastic Beanstalk URL does load.
- Global DNS Propagation Checker [ https://www.whatsmydns.net/ ] confirms that the NS are NOT available.
- The domain name was already successfully transferred months ago.
- I have NOT explicitly changed any hosted zone records since that time.
- Contact information for the domain is verified.
- NS (hosted zone) records for the domain name exactly match whois records and `dig +trace` records.
- There is NOT a hold on the domain name. Nothing in `whois` or on AWS.
- `nslookup` returns the following message on all NS records, with or without the www.

```
nslookup danhenning.us ns-1165.awsdns-17.org
Server:     ns-1165.awsdns-17.org
Address:    2600:9000:5304:8d00::1#53

*** Can't find danhenning.us: No answer
```

Can you help me understand what happened, and how to fix it?  Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Your domain only returns a SOA record. No A or AAAA records. Other than that, it’s working fine.

Comment: Thank you for your input Daniel B. I was able to confirm the information that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to confirm that the domain name could not be resolved, but I don't understand why.

So I recreated the Alias records for the apex and www. sub-domain. Now the website loads.